# Qt creator C++, adding many labels to statusbar

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I would like to add 3 items to statusbar. Shouldn't each be in its own label?

Is that possible? When I tried to add a second label, it gave me an error.

File `mainwindow.h`,

```
QLabel *m_statusLabel;
QLabel *m_pointLabel;
```

File `mainwindow.cpp`,

```
statusBar()->addWidget(m_statusLabel);
statusBar()->addWidget(m_pointLabel);
```

It works perfectly with one label, but when I add a second, then I get the following.

```
Starting C:\Users\Jansu\Desktop\cpp-praktikum05-alus\Joonistamine-build-      desktop\src\bin\Joonistamine.exe...
ASSERT: "d" in file ..\..\include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qscopedpointer.h, line   112
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
C:\Users\Jansu\Desktop\cpp-praktikum05-alus\Joonistamine-build-    desktop\src\bin\Joonistamine.exe exited with code -1073741819
```

Comment: That's probably not caused directly by adding the widgets to the status bar. How are you creating the `QLabel`s?

Comment: Why to add 3 different widgets and not just one which contains everything? Perhaps [QStatusBar](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstatusbar.html) supports only one widget, but you can also try using `addPermanentWidget`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem. I forgot to create QLabels, so I added this:

```
m_statusLabel = new QLabel(this);
m_pointLabel = new QLabel(this);
```